# how to import excel file to MySQL using node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, excel, express, ejs

I'm trying to upload excel sheet data to MySQL for that Can anyone suggest to me on how to import excel file import to MySQL DB / give an example/ link on I'm using express and Node.js?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import Data From Excel To MySql With Node JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51257265/import-data-from-excel-to-mysql-with-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to convert the excel data to a csv

[Convert XLS to CSV on the server in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342425/convert-xls-to-csv-on-the-server-in-node)

Then you can import that csv data file into mysql.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/

Comment: I wanted to import using UI. Your suggestion is without UI I'm using ejs template for import.